Airflow trigger a task only when a particular task is success
I have an use case where I want to execute a task in airflow only when a particular task is success.
Dag is like as below
A --> B -- --> D -> E -> F -> G   
          |
           --> C 

After the task B is finished successfully it goes to either C or D depending on the branch condition.
Now I want to trigger task G only when task D is success. Making the trigger_rule to "all_done" for task G didn't work because when the flow was going to task C then also it is executing. G should only be executed in this branch flow only when task D is success.
Also, If any task fails the overall dag should fail.
How can we implement it in airflow python script ?

can you have task D return different xcom values on success/failure conditions. You can check the xcom then in say another branch/short circuit condition for triggering task G.

@subram Task D is a non python operator, its a dataproc create cluster operator. How can we return xcom from it ? Also since I want G to be execute always irrespective of E or F failed, i need to make the branch_task trigger_rule to "all_done" correct ?

if this create operator has any return value indicating success/failure, can you try to see if it does that using: ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='D', key="return_value")
and for the trigger_rule: none_skipped maybe a better fit (none_skipped: no parent is in a skipped state, i.e. all parents are in a success, failed, or upstream_failed state)
